# how to use jquery show() on li when parent ul is hidden

Tags: javascript, jquery

In one of my function I am hiding the parent unordered list at the beginning of page load and based on certain condition I am showing one of the list element under the hidden parent ul. However, the below code is not working. Using below mentioned function`<ul id="menu">` is hidden completely and I am not able to populate the respective li elements.

HTML mark up

```
<ul id="menu">
    <li id="mainMenuGroup_mostPopular"></li>
    <li id="mainMenuGroup_slots"></li>
    <li id="mainMenuGroup_table"></li>
    <li id="mainMenuGroup_roulette"></li>
    <li id="mainMenuGroup_poker"></li>
    <li id="mainMenuGroup_mobileiOS"></li>
    <li id="mainMenuGroup_mobileAndroid"></li>
    <li id="mainMenuGroup_mobileWinPhone"></li>
</ul>
```

This is my function

```
function deviceDetectionScript() {

    var mobileDetection = new MobileDetect(window.navigator.userAgent);

    if (mobileDetection.mobile()) {

        $('ul#menu').hide();

        if (mobileDetection.os() == 'iOS') {
            $('ul#menu').find('li#mainMenuGroup_mobileiOS').show();
            show_tab_content('mobileiOS');
        }

        if (mobileDetection.os() == 'AndroidOS') {
            $('ul#menu').find('li#mainMenuGroup_mobileAndroid').show();
            show_tab_content('mobileAndroid');
        }

        if (mobileDetection.os() == 'WindowsMobileOS' || mobileDetection.os() == 'WindowsPhoneOS') {
            $('ul#menu').find('li#mainMenuGroup_mobileWinPhone').show();
            show_tab_content('mobileWinPhone');
        }

    } else {
        $('ul#menu').show();
    }
}
```

Comment: How comes that all `<li>` don't have closing tags?

Comment: Please don't pay attention to the mark up. Since I am populating them dynamically and I just copied the mark up from firebug console. I will amend the HTML markup in my question.

Comment: i think that the best answer is: you can;t show child elemnt if parent isn't displayed. Try hiding li elements instead of ul

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, you can not show child elements if the parent element is hidden. You need to hide all the `li`s except the specific one. You can use `.not()` method for that.

```
 if (mobileDetection.mobile()) {
     if (mobileDetection.os() == 'iOS') {
         $('ul#menu').find("li").not('#mainMenuGroup_mobileiOS').hide();
         show_tab_content('mobileiOS');
     }
```

Answer (score 3):

you don't need to hide ul. you should hide li except you want to show li. like this

```
$('#menu > li').not('#mainMenuGroup_table').hide();
```